# Python Pandas groupby syntax

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, group-by

Right now, I am trying to replace a stored procedure with a Python service, and the temp tables with Pandas dataframes. But I'm stuck on this:

```
SELECT a, b, FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(c) / x) * x), MAX(c)
FROM foo
GROUP BY a, b, FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(c) / x) * x)
```

where a, b, and c are columns in foo, and x is a variable

I know that the Python Pandas groupby works like this:

```
fooGroupBy = foo.groupby(['a', 'b'])
```

but I can't figure out how to get the FROM_UNIXTIME part in.

Or would it be better to do

```
fooGroupBy = foo.groupby(['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

and then take the 'c' column and perform the function on that?

Comment: Is 'c' a date time column ?

Comment: I'll suggest you list the steps to what you want to achieve. Makes it easier for people to respond.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) FROM_UNIXTIME on column, c
2. Do groupby on ['a', 'b', 'c']